# ERROR getting 'name' attribute: attribute is not a string value

Tags: android, android-manifest

Uploading my apk file to google play makes this error:

> Your APK cannot be analyzed using aapt. Error output: Failed to run
>   aapt dump badging: ERROR getting 'name' attribute: attribute is not a
>   string value

Since I know that this problem is within my manifest file, I have put it here:

**AndroidManifext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.altontech.newsimpay">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay.Classes.Model.AnalyticsApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">

        <receiver
            android:name="com.adjust.sdk.AdjustReferrerReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".Receivers.SmsListener">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay.Activities.Introduction"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay.Activities.Main"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:taskAffinity="ir.altontech.simpay"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SpecificPage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="ir.altontech.simpay.specific"
                    android:scheme="simpay" />
                <data
                    android:host="ad.simpay.ir"
                    android:scheme="http" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SplashActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:taskAffinity="ir.altontech.simpay"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.FastCharge"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:taskAffinity="ir.altontech.simpay"
            android:theme="@style/fast_charge_theme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay.Activities.BarcodeScanner" />
        <activity
            android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay.Activities.FinalTrainTicket"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay.Activities.VideoPlayer"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:taskAffinity="ir.altontech.simpay" />
        <activity android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay.Activities.CallBack">
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="ir.altontech.simpay.callback"
                    android:scheme="simpay" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".Classes.Services.GCMService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <!-- services -->

        <!-- registration process service -->
        <service
            android:name="ir.altontech.cloudmessaging.core.registrationprocess.RegistrationProcessService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="co.shariftech.pushnotification.intent.action.START_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- registration process token refresher service -->
        <service
            android:name="ir.altontech.cloudmessaging.core.registrationprocess.RegistrationProcessTokenRefresherService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- push notification service -->
        <service
            android:name="ir.altontech.cloudmessaging.core.pushnotification.PushNotificationService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- receivers -->

        <!-- google cloud messaging receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have checked all `android:name` attributes and couldn't find the problem. Thank you all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396591/cant-update-my-app-in-google-play-aapt-error

Comment: Did you checked error by running `aapt` command locally? If not please do that and update your question.

Comment: Yes I tried that. Problem is it doesn't tell specifically which line and where exactly is making this error.

Comment: Have you tried this one before http://stackoverflow.com/a/17009646/4376058

Comment: within your manifest, could you indicate the part that has changed since your previous upload.. as you pointed out, you didn't face any issues in prior versions

Comment: The only change in my manifest file after the last successful upload, is the "FastChargeActivity".

Answer (score 3):

so after searching a little I have found three options for you to do:

1- if you have something as follows (which I see you don't ):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="@string/alarm_auto_sync" >
</intent-filter>
```

you should hard code the string and remove @string

2- follow [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=46311) to see what could and have been done to solve this issue as I found out this might be the bug of

> aapt dump badging

3- if you have values-fa and values-en and other string values as such you should copy your android:name to values.

for more information on these options visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008364/aapt-error-getting-androidname-attribute-attribute-is-not-a-string-value) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745167/error-while-uploading-application-to-android-market)

hope this helps

Comment: Yes, in my case string resources in intent filter were the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can go for below suggested link. I hope it helps you.

[aapt ERROR getting 'android:name' attribute: attribute is not a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008364/aapt-error-getting-androidname-attribute-attribute-is-not-a-string-value)

Thank you

Comment: Must be put in comment.

Comment: I've go through this link before.

Answer (score 2):

I think this issue is for different reasons for different people. But in all cases it is the `android:name` attribute that needs to be investigated. When I encountered it and read some of the replies here, I found mine. Adding it here, just so that it can help someone in future.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="@string/broadcast_action" />
</intent-filter>
```

I had defined `broadcast_action` in `strings.xml` It worked when I changed that to a hardcoded string. AAPT does not accept a string reference here.

Comment: Ran into the same issue with `<permission/>`

Answer (score 1):

check this link from [**google**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

```
      android:name="string"
```

the document says , your syntax of `android:name` element should be **String** .

i think , your manifest file project is good . check your manifest library .maybe you add some library and get this error . also check your project and your library have `android:name` element .

hope this help you .

Answer (score 1):

All thing seems good in your `AndroidManifest.xml` except `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` position. Please give a try by moving `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` from `<application></application>` tag to `<manifest></manifest>` tag like this.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.altontech.newsimpay"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<application
    android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay.Classes.Model.AnalyticsApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">
</application>
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Comment: In prior versions, this tag was there and there wasn't any error uploading apk to google play. :(

Comment: Ok, I'll test it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you have defined your custom permission:

```
<permission
    android:name="ir.altontech.newsimpay.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

But in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining.html#defining) you can see:

> You **need to** supply both a label and description for the permission.

I'm not sure whether this may be the case, but at least docs urge you to define **label** and **description**.

Comment: This permission was there and was exactly like this in older versions and aapt wasn't getting any error. But I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any library project as module in your project that having

```
 android:label="@string/app_name"
```

in their `string.xml` file then it may coause of your problem.

So your pass hardcode app name in your manifest file for app name like below.

```
 android:label="PASS YoUR APP NAME HERE not from string.xml"
```

Comment: I've checked out libraries manifests and all of them have string labels. :(

Comment: so pass app name in your project  `AndroidManifest.xml`  file hard coded

Comment: I've test that too before and there was no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is multi-lingual, then make sure you have provided the translatable as false in the string.xml or provide the app_name in the other files as well. I too got this error once and that was the cause.

Comment: Nope, My app isn't multi lingual.

Answer (score 1):

may be on of your class had been moved to another package check if all of your classes are in the same package path like manifest

```
        android:name="ir.altontech.cloudmessaging.core.pushnotification.PushNotificationService"
```

Comment: It belongs to some library and it isn't mine. I double checked all of my classes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to follow [java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Since from your code I cant realy tell is your `Application Class` an Enclosing class

Try using `.Classes.Model.AnalyticsApplication` instead of `ir.altontech.newsimpay.Classes.Model.AnalyticsApplication`

Comment: Applying what you had said, isn't different since using .Classes... will be replace by full package name.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the broadcast intent-filter name which was referenced from the string file was deleted.
If you are using multi-module project check all manifest in Android Studio to see an error. `android:name` can refer to any `android:name` attribute, not just the one in application tag.

Merged manifest can be found at

```
app/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/<flavour>
```

Answer (score -1):

In Android we need to assign the strings through string.xml file.

```
 String name - "xyz app"
```

this is not the recommended approach

```
   String name = "@string/app_name"
```

In String.xml Store this name as

```
 <string name="app_name">xyz app</string>
```

complete in android programming we need to follow this approach for using strings